# Events firing before 'Me.Startup' sub has finished in vb.net vsto outlook addin

Tags: vb.net, vsto, outlook-addin

I've written all the code to initialize variables in

```
Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
```

But part of my code is in a sub:

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(EntryIDCollection As String) Handles Application.NewMailEx
```

I've noticed that if there's email waiting for me when I start outlook, the `newmailex` sub will start running at the same time as (or before) the `me.startup` sub.

Is there an event other than `me.startup` that comes even earlier, and is blocking, so that I can be sure that all my variables are ready when I get my first mails?

Comment: I can remove the `handles Application.NewMailEx` from my sub, and add the handle at runtime with: `AddHandler Application.NewMailEx, AddressOf Application_NewMailEx` but this does mean that the interception of mail during loading is disabled completely, and a whole load of emails will go missing every time someone turns their PC off for the night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize all your variables in a single sub (CheckInitialize?) that checks a global/class flag, initializes all variables, and sets the global flag to true. You can call that sub from both Startup and NewMailEx event handlers.

Comment: Thanks - a good idea. Thinking about it, I could just add the global flag and start the NewMailEx with a 'while not' loop to wait for the end of the init code.

Comment: There is no need to - just always call CheckInitialize, which will initialize everything if the internal flag is not yet set and do nothing if it is set.

Comment: Well, yeah, unless the initialization is half-done because the mail arrived while it was already taking place. The wait loop is safer.

Comment: It is impossible - both event handlers run on the same (main) thread, so there are no concurrency issues.

Comment: So surely every time you load outlook it runs the `me.startup` before `newmailex` every time... and so if the initialisation is in `me.startup` then it'll always complete before `newmailex`?

Comment: It does not matter if you call that sub from both event handlers.

Comment: Ideally. But there are cases where Office applications can be automated from other applications. In such scenarios, you may skip the startup routine.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for your answer. I'll implement it now.